# Value not being returned using Knit

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to  have a table and some values returned from a function, using this:

```
`r TabelaTipos("T")`

`r MinDPA`
```

It was supposed to return a table and the min standard deviation, but its only returning an error. If I remove `r MinDPA`, it returns the table like a charm, but if I keep it, I get:

```
Error in eval(expr,envir,enclos): object 'MinDPA' not found Calls: <anonymous> ... in_dir -> inline_exec -> withVisible -> eval -> stopped execution
```

The function I am using to produce results is:

```
TabelaTipos <- function(Qual){
TiposMotivA <- DadosA[,6:58]
TiposMotivB <- DadosB[,6:58]
LinhasA <- nrow(TiposMotivA)
LinhasB <- nrow(TiposMotivB)
ColunasA <- ncol(TiposMotivA)
ColunasB <- ncol(TiposMotivB)
colnames(TiposMotivA) <- paste("Q",1:ColunasA,sep="")
colnames(TiposMotivB) <- paste("Q",1:ColunasB,sep="")
TiposMotivA <- TiposMotivA[complete.cases(TiposMotivA),]
TiposMotivB <- TiposMotivB[complete.cases(TiposMotivB),]
ModaLinhaA <- apply(TiposMotivA[,1:21], 1, function(x) sum(x == Mode(x)))
ModaLinhaB <- apply(TiposMotivB[,1:21], 1, function(x) sum(x == Mode(x)))
TiposMotivA <- TiposMotivA[ModaLinhaA/21 < .762,]
TiposMotivB <- TiposMotivB[ModaLinhaB/21 < .762,]
ModaLinhaC <- apply(TiposMotivA[,22:53],1, function(x) sum(x == Mode(x)))
ModaLinhaD <- apply(TiposMotivB[,22:53],1, function(x) sum(x == Mode(x)))
TiposMotivA <- TiposMotivA[ModaLinhaC/21 < .762,]
TiposMotivB <- TiposMotivB[ModaLinhaD/21 < .762,]
TiposMotivA <- cbind(TiposMotivA,FIB = rowSums(TiposMotivA[,22:53]))
TiposMotivB <- cbind(TiposMotivB,FIB = rowSums(TiposMotivB[,22:53]))
switch(Qual,
       "T"={
         # Ok  
       },
       "MF"={
           TiposMotivA <- TiposMotivA[TiposMotivA$FIB>=81,]
           TiposMotivB <- TiposMotivB[TiposMotivB$FIB>=81,]
       },
       "F"={
           TiposMotivA <- TiposMotivA[TiposMotivA$FIB>=61 & TiposMotivA$FIB <81,]
           TiposMotivB <- TiposMotivB[TiposMotivB$FIB>=61 & TiposMotivB$FIB <81,]
       },
       "S"={
           TiposMotivA <- TiposMotivA[TiposMotivA$FIB>=41 & TiposMotivA$FIB <61,]
           TiposMotivB <- TiposMotivB[TiposMotivB$FIB>=41 & TiposMotivB$FIB <61,]
       },
       "I"={
           TiposMotivA <- TiposMotivA[TiposMotivA$FIB>=21 & TiposMotivA$FIB <41,]
           TiposMotivB <- TiposMotivB[TiposMotivB$FIB>=21 & TiposMotivB$FIB <41,]
       },
       "MI"={
           TiposMotivA <- TiposMotivA[TiposMotivA$FIB <20,]
           TiposMotivB <- TiposMotivB[TiposMotivB$FIB <20,]
       },stop("Ok")
       )
    TiposA <- transmute(TiposMotivA, A=(Q1+Q11)/2,B=(Q10+Q21)/2,C=(Q6+Q15)/2,D=(Q5+Q14)/2,E=(Q9+Q20)/2,F=(Q7+Q16)/2,G=(Q2+Q17)/2,H=(Q4+Q13)/2,I=(Q3+Q8+Q19)/3,J=(Q12+Q18)/2,K=(A+B+C)/3,L=(D+E+F)/3,M=(G+H)/2,N=(I+J)/2)
    TiposB <- transmute(TiposMotivB, A=(Q1+Q11)/2,B=(Q10+Q21)/2,C=(Q6+Q15)/2,D=(Q5+Q14)/2,E=(Q9+Q20)/2,F=(Q7+Q16)/2,G=(Q2+Q17)/2,H=(Q4+Q13)/2,I=(Q3+Q8+Q19)/3,J=(Q12+Q18)/2,K=(A+B+C)/3,L=(D+E+F)/3,M=(G+H)/2,N=(I+J)/2)
ResultTiposAB <- format(round(matrix(c(mean(TiposA$A),mean(TiposA$B),mean(TiposA$C),mean(TiposA$D),mean(TiposA$E),mean(TiposA$F),mean(TiposA$G),mean(TiposA$H),mean(TiposA$I),mean(TiposA$J),mean(TiposA$K),mean(TiposA$L),mean(TiposA$M),mean(TiposA$N),Mode(TiposA$A),Mode(TiposA$B),Mode(TiposA$C),Mode(TiposA$D),Mode(TiposA$E),Mode(TiposA$F),Mode(TiposA$G),Mode(TiposA$H),Mode(TiposA$I),Mode(TiposA$J),Mode(TiposA$K),Mode(TiposA$L),Mode(TiposA$M),Mode(TiposA$N),sd(TiposA$A),sd(TiposA$B),sd(TiposA$C),sd(TiposA$D),sd(TiposA$E),sd(TiposA$F),sd(TiposA$G),sd(TiposA$H),sd(TiposA$I),sd(TiposA$J),sd(TiposA$K),sd(TiposA$L),sd(TiposA$M),sd(TiposA$N),mean(TiposB$A),mean(TiposB$B),mean(TiposB$C),mean(TiposB$D),mean(TiposB$E),mean(TiposB$F),mean(TiposB$G),mean(TiposB$H),mean(TiposB$I),mean(TiposB$J),mean(TiposB$K),mean(TiposB$L),mean(TiposB$M),mean(TiposB$N),Mode(TiposB$A),Mode(TiposB$B),Mode(TiposB$C),Mode(TiposB$D),Mode(TiposB$E),Mode(TiposB$F),Mode(TiposB$G),Mode(TiposB$H),Mode(TiposB$I),Mode(TiposB$J),Mode(TiposB$K),Mode(TiposB$L),Mode(TiposB$M),Mode(TiposB$N),sd(TiposB$A),sd(TiposB$B),sd(TiposB$C),sd(TiposB$D),sd(TiposB$E),sd(TiposB$F),sd(TiposB$G),sd(TiposB$H),sd(TiposB$I),sd(TiposB$J),sd(TiposB$K),sd(TiposB$L),sd(TiposB$M),sd(TiposB$N)),ncol=6),digits=2),decimal.mark=",")
rownames(ResultTiposAB) <- c("Autodeterminação","Hedonismo","Estimulação","Segurança","Tradição","Conformidade","Poder","Realização","Universalismo","Benevolência","Abertura à mudança","Conservação","Autopromoção","Autotranscedência")
colnames(ResultTiposAB) <- c("Média","Moda","Desvio Padrão","Média","Moda","Desvio Padrão")
ResultTiposAB.table <- as.table(ResultTiposAB)
MinDP <- format(round(min(c(sd(TiposA$A),sd(TiposA$B),sd(TiposA$C),sd(TiposA$D),sd(TiposA$E),sd(TiposA$F),sd(TiposA$G),sd(TiposA$H),sd(TiposA$I),sd(TiposA$J),sd(TiposA$K),sd(TiposA$L),sd(TiposA$M),sd(TiposA$N),sd(TiposB$A),sd(TiposB$B),sd(TiposB$C),sd(TiposB$D),sd(TiposB$E),sd(TiposB$F),sd(TiposB$G),sd(TiposB$H),sd(TiposB$I),sd(TiposB$J),sd(TiposB$K),sd(TiposB$L),sd(TiposB$M),sd(TiposB$N))), digits=2),decimal.mark=",")
MaxDP <- format(round(max(c(sd(TiposA$A),sd(TiposA$B),sd(TiposA$C),sd(TiposA$D),sd(TiposA$E),sd(TiposA$F),sd(TiposA$G),sd(TiposA$H),sd(TiposA$I),sd(TiposA$J),sd(TiposA$K),sd(TiposA$L),sd(TiposA$M),sd(TiposA$N),sd(TiposB$A),sd(TiposB$B),sd(TiposB$C),sd(TiposB$D),sd(TiposB$E),sd(TiposB$F),sd(TiposB$G),sd(TiposB$H),sd(TiposB$I),sd(TiposB$J),sd(TiposB$K),sd(TiposB$L),sd(TiposB$M),sd(TiposB$N))),digits=2),decimal.mark=",")
MinDPA <- format(round(min(c(sd(TiposA$A),sd(TiposA$B),sd(TiposA$C),sd(TiposA$D),sd(TiposA$E),sd(TiposA$F),sd(TiposA$G),sd(TiposA$H),sd(TiposA$I),sd(TiposA$J),sd(TiposA$K),sd(TiposA$L),sd(TiposA$M),sd(TiposA$N))), digits=2),decimal.mark=",")
MinDPB <- format(round(min(c(sd(TiposB$A),sd(TiposB$B),sd(TiposB$C),sd(TiposB$D),sd(TiposB$E),sd(TiposB$F),sd(TiposB$G),sd(TiposB$H),sd(TiposB$I),sd

(TiposB$J),sd(TiposB$K),sd(TiposB$L),sd(TiposB$M),sd(TiposB$N))),digits=2),decimal.mark=",")
MaxDPA <- format(round(max(c(sd(TiposA$A),sd(TiposA$B),sd(TiposA$C),sd(TiposA$D),sd(TiposA$E),sd(TiposA$F),sd(TiposA$G),sd(TiposA$H),sd(TiposA$I),sd(TiposA$J),sd(TiposA$K),sd(TiposA$L),sd(TiposA$M),sd(TiposA$N))), digits=2),decimal.mark=",")
MaxDPB <- format(round(max(c(sd(TiposB$A),sd(TiposB$B),sd(TiposB$C),sd(TiposB$D),sd(TiposB$E),sd(TiposB$F),sd(TiposB$G),sd(TiposB$H),sd(TiposB$I),sd(TiposB$J),sd(TiposB$K),sd(TiposB$L),sd(TiposB$M),sd(TiposB$N))),digits=2),decimal.mark=",")
return(kable(ResultTiposAB.table, format = "markdown", align = "r"))
}
```

I have tested many things. If I run code on console it works, but if I run it at Knit, it doesnt. 
The oddest thing, is that this works

```
`r MinDP`
`r MaxDP`
```

But any of these didnt Work

```
`r MinDPA`
`r MinDPB`
`r MaxDPA`
`r MaxDPB`
```

Here is my data:

```
> dput(head(DadosA))
structure(list(genero = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), idade = c(3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L), renda.mês = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), escolaridade = c(3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), liderança = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L), Q1.Autodeterminação.criatividade = c(5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L), Q2.Poder.riqueza = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
4L), Q3.Universalismo.igualdade = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 3L), 
    Q4.Realização...admiração = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 3L), Q5.Segurança...Ambiente.Seguro = c(6L, 
    5L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 4L), Q6.Estimulação...Surpresas = c(6L, 5L, 
    4L, 6L, 7L, 5L), Q7.Conformidade...Obediência = c(7L, 5L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 4L), Q8.Universalismo.diversidade = c(6L, 5L, 
    4L, 6L, 7L, 3L), Q9.Tradição...modéstia = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
    7L, 4L), Q10.Hedonismo...prazer = c(6L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L
    ), Q11.Autodeterminação.liberdade = c(6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L), Q12.Benevolência...solidariedade = c(6L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 
    7L, 6L), Q13.Realização...reconhecimento = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 
    7L, 2L, 4L), Q14.Segurança...Ordem.Social = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 
    6L, 2L, 4L), Q15.Estimulação...Aventura = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 
    3L, 6L), Q16.Conformidade...bom.comportamento = c(4L, 6L, 
    4L, 7L, 6L, 4L), Q17.Poder.respeito = c(6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    5L), Q18.Benevolência...lealdade = c(7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L), Q19.Universalismo.sustentabilidadde = c(4L, 6L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 6L), Q20.Tradição...religião = c(4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 
    7L, 6L), Q21.Hedonismo...diversão = c(6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L), X1.atividade.física = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), X2.alimentação = c(3L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L), X3.saúde = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L), 
    X4.remuneração = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L), X5.bom.trabalho = c(3L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), X6.bom.sono = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L), X7.boa.aparência = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), X8.boa.disposição = c(2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), X9.vida.confortãvel = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 3L), X10.controle.do.orçamento = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    0L, 2L), X11.dever.cumprido = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L), 
    X12.consegue.poupar = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L), X13.tem.objetivos.futuros = c(3L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), X14.alcança.metas = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 3L), X15.é.reconhecido = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), X16.compra.o.que.deseja = c(3L, 
    4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), X17.é.positivo = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L), X18.aprende.com.erros = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L), X19.lida.bem.com.emoções = c(3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 3L), X20.boa.gestao.do.tempo = c(3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 0L, 2L), X21.valoriza.coisas.simples = c(2L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), X22.aproveita.oportunidades = c(3L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), X23.vida.pessoal.e.profissional.em.equilíbrio = c(2L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L), X24.satisfação.afetiva = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L), X25.compartilha.conhecimento = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 3L), X26.encontra.amigos.familia = c(1L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 3L), X27.orgulha.se.do.seu.caminho = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 3L), X28.ajuda.a.comunidade = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 
    2L), X29.exerce.cidadania = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L), X30.contato.com.a.natureza = c(1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), X31.respeita.diversidade = c(2L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 3L), X32.preserva.o.planeta = c(1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L)), .Names = c("genero", "idade", "renda.mês", "escolaridade", 
"liderança", "Q1.Autodeterminação.criatividade", "Q2.Poder.riqueza", 
"Q3.Universalismo.igualdade", "Q4.Realização...admiração", "Q5.Segurança...Ambiente.Seguro", 
"Q6.Estimulação...Surpresas", "Q7.Conformidade...Obediência", 
"Q8.Universalismo.diversidade", "Q9.Tradição...modéstia", "Q10.Hedonismo...prazer", 
"Q11.Autodeterminação.liberdade", "Q12.Benevolência...solidariedade", 
"Q13.Realização...reconhecimento", "Q14.Segurança...Ordem.Social", 
"Q15.Estimulação...Aventura", "Q16.Conformidade...bom.comportamento", 
"Q17.Poder.respeito", "Q18.Benevolência...lealdade", "Q19.Universalismo.sustentabilidadde", 
"Q20.Tradição...religião", "Q21.Hedonismo...diversão", "X1.atividade.física", 
"X2.alimentação", "X3.saúde", "X4.remuneração", "X5.bom.trabalho", 
"X6.bom.sono", "X7.boa.aparência", "X8.boa.disposição", "X9.vida.confortãvel", 
"X10.controle.do.orçamento", "X11.dever.cumprido", "X12.consegue.poupar", 
"X13.tem.objetivos.futuros", "X14.alcança.metas", "X15.é.reconhecido", 
"X16.compra.o.que.deseja", "X17.é.positivo", "X18.aprende.com.erros", 
"X19.lida.bem.com.emoções", "X20.boa.gestao.do.tempo", "X21.valoriza.coisas.simples", 
"X22.aproveita.oportunidades", "X23.vida.pessoal.e.profissional.em.equilíbrio", 
"X24.satisfação.afetiva", "X25.compartilha.conhecimento", "X26.encontra.amigos.familia", 
"X27.orgulha.se.do.seu.caminho", "X28.ajuda.a.comunidade", "X29.exerce.cidadania", 
"X30.contato.com.a.natureza", "X31.respeita.diversidade", "X32.preserva.o.planeta"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(DadosB))
structure(list(genero = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), idade = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), renda.mês = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L), escolaridade = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L), liderança = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Q1.Autodeterminação.criatividade = c(7L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L), Q2.Poder.riqueza = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
3L), Q3.Universalismo.igualdade = c(7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L), 
    Q4.Realização...admiração = c(7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 2L), Q5.Segurança...Ambiente.Seguro = c(7L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L), Q6.Estimulação...Surpresas = c(7L, 7L, 
    4L, 6L, 7L, 3L), Q7.Conformidade...Obediência = c(7L, 4L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 6L), Q8.Universalismo.diversidade = c(7L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 4L, 7L), Q9.Tradição...modéstia = c(7L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L), Q10.Hedonismo...prazer = c(7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L
    ), Q11.Autodeterminação.liberdade = c(7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
    4L), Q12.Benevolência...solidariedade = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    6L, 7L), Q13.Realização...reconhecimento = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
    7L, 5L, 2L), Q14.Segurança...Ordem.Social = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 
    6L, 5L, 4L), Q15.Estimulação...Aventura = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 1L), Q16.Conformidade...bom.comportamento = c(7L, 2L, 
    2L, 7L, 3L, 7L), Q17.Poder.respeito = c(1L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 
    4L), Q18.Benevolência...lealdade = c(7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L), Q19.Universalismo.sustentabilidadde = c(7L, 7L, 6L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L), Q20.Tradição...religião = c(7L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L), Q21.Hedonismo...diversão = c(7L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 
    5L), X1.atividade.física = c(4L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L), X2.alimentação = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), X3.saúde = c(4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L), 
    X4.remuneração = c(4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), X5.bom.trabalho = c(2L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L), X6.bom.sono = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    4L), X7.boa.aparência = c(3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 3L), X8.boa.disposição = c(4L, 
    0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L), X9.vida.confortãvel = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L), X10.controle.do.orçamento = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L), X11.dever.cumprido = c(4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), 
    X12.consegue.poupar = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), X13.tem.objetivos.futuros = c(4L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L), X14.alcança.metas = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L), X15.é.reconhecido = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L), X16.compra.o.que.deseja = c(2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L), X17.é.positivo = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L), X18.aprende.com.erros = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), X19.lida.bem.com.emoções = c(2L, 
    4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), X20.boa.gestao.do.tempo = c(2L, 0L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), X21.valoriza.coisas.simples = c(4L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), X22.aproveita.oportunidades = c(2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), X23.vida.pessoal.e.profissional.em.equilíbrio = c(2L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), X24.satisfação.afetiva = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L), X25.compartilha.conhecimento = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L), X26.encontra.amigos.familia = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L), X27.orgulha.se.do.seu.caminho = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L), X28.ajuda.a.comunidade = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    3L), X29.exerce.cidadania = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L), X30.contato.com.a.natureza = c(4L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L), X31.respeita.diversidade = c(4L, 2L, 
    4L, 3L, 2L, 4L), X32.preserva.o.planeta = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 3L)), .Names = c("genero", "idade", "renda.mês", "escolaridade", 
"liderança", "Q1.Autodeterminação.criatividade", "Q2.Poder.riqueza", 
"Q3.Universalismo.igualdade", "Q4.Realização...admiração", "Q5.Segurança...Ambiente.Seguro", 
"Q6.Estimulação...Surpresas", "Q7.Conformidade...Obediência", 
"Q8.Universalismo.diversidade", "Q9.Tradição...modéstia", "Q10.Hedonismo...prazer", 
"Q11.Autodeterminação.liberdade", "Q12.Benevolência...solidariedade", 
"Q13.Realização...reconhecimento", "Q14.Segurança...Ordem.Social", 
"Q15.Estimulação...Aventura", "Q16.Conformidade...bom.comportamento", 
"Q17.Poder.respeito", "Q18.Benevolência...lealdade", "Q19.Universalismo.sustentabilidadde", 
"Q20.Tradição...religião", "Q21.Hedonismo...diversão", "X1.atividade.física", 
"X2.alimentação", "X3.saúde", "X4.remuneração", "X5.bom.trabalho", 
"X6.bom.sono", "X7.boa.aparência", "X8.boa.disposição", "X9.vida.confortãvel", 
"X10.controle.do.orçamento", "X11.dever.cumprido", "X12.consegue.poupar", 
"X13.tem.objetivos.futuros", "X14.alcança.metas", "X15.é.reconhecido", 
"X16.compra.o.que.deseja", "X17.é.positivo", "X18.aprende.com.erros", 
"X19.lida.bem.com.emoções", "X20.boa.gestao.do.tempo", "X21.valoriza.coisas.simples", 
"X22.aproveita.oportunidades", "X23.vida.pessoal.e.profissional.em.equilíbrio", 
"X24.satisfação.afetiva", "X25.compartilha.conhecimento", "X26.encontra.amigos.familia", 
"X27.orgulha.se.do.seu.caminho", "X28.ajuda.a.comunidade", "X29.exerce.cidadania", 
"X30.contato.com.a.natureza", "X31.respeita.diversidade", "X32.preserva.o.planeta"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any clues on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not assign the result of your function to an object, so it is discarded and you cannot access it afterwards. Try something like :

```
`r result <- TabelaTipos("T")`

`r result[1]`
```

Also, you should not have two return calls in your function. Either merge them in a list or just print the table instead of returning it.

```
## In the function definition
return(list(c(MinDPA, MinDPB, MaxDPA, MaxDPB),
            kable(ResultTiposAB.table, format = "markdown", align = "r"))

## Afterwards :
result <- TableaTipos("T")

## print MinDPA
result[[1]][1]

## print kable
print(result[[2]])
```

OR

```
## Function Definition
return(c(MinDPA, MinDPB, MaxDPA, MaxDPB))
print(kable(ResultTiposAB.table, format = "markdown", align = "r"))
```

Finally, if you want to call your MinDPA with something like `result$MinDPA`, you should return a data.frame rather than a vector :

```
return(data.frame(MinDPA=MinDPA, MinDPB=MinDPB, MaxDPA=MaxDPA, MaxDPB=MaxDPB))

result <- TableaTipos("T")

## print MinDPA
result$MinDPA
```